# Query to match a specific element of an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm unable to understand why my current query isn't returning the correct results, here is my code:

```
db.getCollection('players')
.find({'ratings.gameRatingType' : 'standard', 'ratings.rating' : { $gt: 234, $lt: 235 } })
```

Here is a screenshot of the expanded result:

[image: Mongoose Nested Array Query]

Even when I query a rating range 0 - 1000 (all possible) my result does not return all results?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple criteria on a particuar array element is what [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is for:

```js
db.getCollection('players').find({
  "ratings": { "$elemMatch": {
      "gameRatingType" : 'standard',
      "rating" : { "$gt": 234, "$lt": 235 } 
  }}
})
```

Otherwise the query is just looking to see that "any" array element contains the criteria you want. This ensures it is on the "same" array element, not just on elements contained somewhere in the document.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, I didn't come across `$elemMatch` in the Mongoose Docs.

Comment: @MattWebb Mongoose only talks about its own API "methods". The [query and update operator syntax](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/) ( and more ) is on the official MongoDB site.